# Domino form not showing buttons or hotspots with javascript code

Tags: lotus-domino

Domino web app (traditional, not XPages)

Simple form with a single subform.   I add a button and a hotspot, each with action set to Web/Javascript

Javascript :  alert('hello');

Neither the button nor the hotspot are visible in the browswer.  No hide formulas on either.

DB Setting of "Use JavaScript when generating pages" is checked.

Can anyone point out something that I am missing?    I have double-checked there's nothing like a div set to dislay:none; or hide formula in place.

Domino 11.01 on server
Browsers: Chrome and Firefox

Comment: Did you check source code? Does it show anything in there? If you put Normal Text above and below the buttons: does it show? What does max. Internet Access in ACL say?

Comment: Do Form or Subform happen to have the design property "Hide design element from: Web Browsers" set (Properties pane when selecting the design element from list of design elements)

Comment: Do you have any passthru HTML on the form? If so, check the syntax and especially look for unclosed quotes, tags, or comments.

Comment: I'll answer the three response above in one post:
1.) I removed EVERYTHING from the subform but the button...it still does not show.
2.) No the subform is set to show both for Notes and the Web
3.)  See response to #1

I can't figure this out, I have other JavaScript buttons on other subforms that have never given a problem.   I am having to resort to a button with formula language, which causes the form to jump when it is clicked (resetting to an anchor it sets automatically I presume) and this is very annoying.

Comment: Big clue I just discovered.  I moved the button to the form instead of the subform and now it it showing.  Something about the subform or the form/subform relatioinship that I have not seen documented anywhere

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured it out...I had accidentally included the button as set to pass-thru HTML....as soon as I took that checkmark off, the button now shows.   It's not evident that is set without highlighting the button and looking at 'text' menu option.

Thanks for trying to help me.

Matt

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).